# How to create mutiple mobs entities with the current given code?

Tags: java, swing, collision-detection

I am currently making a tower shooter type game that has a turret at the bottom of the screen. It shoots multiple bullets (or is suppose too, I haven't made it work properly yet) ever few second or so. I have a enemy guy come from the top of the screen and make his way to the bottom unless the bullets collide with the enemy. If it does collide, the y value is set back to to the top of the screen and the enemy comes down again from another x value position. What I am trying to do is make multiple enemies come down from the top, one after the other in different x value positions, but I can't figure out how to make multiple version of the enemy with the collision checking it too.

```
private Graphics2D graphics;
private Animation mobAnimation = new Animation();
private int mobX = (int) ((Math.random() * 1252) + 28);
private int mobY = -55;
private int bulletX = ((width / 2) - (22 / 2));
private int bulletY = (height - 100);
private Timer mobs = new Timer(200, new MobListener());
private Timer bullet = new Timer(100, new BulletListener());
private BufferedImage MobAnimation;

// Draws the bullets.
public void drawBullets() {
    // bulletCollision = new Ellipse2D.Double(bulletX, bulletY, 22, 22);

    BufferedImage Bullets = bullets.getSprite(0, 0, 13, 13);

    float centerX = (getWidth() / 2);
    float centerY = (getHeight() - (75 / 2));
    double angle = Math.atan2((centerY - mouse.getMouseY()), (centerX - mouse.getMouseX())) - (Math.PI / 2);

    graphics.rotate(angle, (getWidth() / 2), (getHeight() - (75 / 2)));
    graphics.drawImage(Bullets, bulletX, bulletY, 22, 22, null);
    // graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    // graphics.draw(bulletCollision);
    graphics.rotate(-angle, (getWidth() / 2), (getHeight() - (75 / 2)));
}

// Part of the bullets.
private class BulletListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent bae) {
        bulletY -= 20;

        if (bulletY <= -350) {
            bulletY = (getHeight() - 100);
        }

        if (bulletCollisionCheck()) {
            mobY = -55;
            bulletY = getHeight() - 100;
            mobX = (int) ((Math.random() * 1252) + 28);
            finalScore += 10;
        }
    }
}

// Draws the mobs.
public void drawMobs() {
    // mobCollision = new Ellipse2D.Double(((mobX - (56 / 2)) - 3), (mobY - 56 / 2), 56, 56);

    BufferedImage Mob1[] = new BufferedImage[4];
    Mob1[0] = mob1.getSprite(0, 0, 32, 35);
    Mob1[1] = mob1.getSprite(32, 0, 32, 35);
    Mob1[2] = mob1.getSprite(64, 0, 32, 35);
    Mob1[3] = mob1.getSprite(32, 0, 32, 35);

    for (int i = 0; i < Mob1.length; i++) {
        mobAnimation.addFrame(Mob1[i]);
    }

    graphics.drawImage(MobAnimation, (mobX - (56 / 2)), (mobY - (56 / 2)), 52, 55, null);
    // graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    // graphics.draw(mobCollision);
}

// Part of the mobs.
private class MobListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent mae) {
        MobAnimation = mobAnimation.getNextFrame();
        mobY += 10;

        float dx = (mobX - (getWidth() / 2));
        float dy = (mobY - (getHeight() - 2));
        float radiusSum = ((56 / 2) + (256 / 2));
        float distanceBetweenCircles = (float) Math.sqrt((dx * dx) + (dy * dy));
        float distanceToMove = radiusSum - distanceBetweenCircles;

        if (mobY >= (getHeight() + 55)) {
            mobY = -55;
            health -= 10;
        }

        if (health <= 15) {
            gameState = GAME_OVER;
            health = 300;
            mobs.stop();
            scenes.stop();
            timer.stop();
            mobY -= 55;
        }

        if (mobCollisionCheck()) {
            if (mobX < (getWidth() / 2)) {
                mobX -= distanceToMove;
            } else if (mobX > (getWidth() / 2)) {
                mobX += distanceToMove;
            } else if (mobX == (getWidth() / 2)) {
                mobX += distanceToMove;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is where it checks for collision:

```
// Checks the collision of mobs.
public boolean mobCollisionCheck() {
    float dx = (mobX - (getWidth() / 2));
    float dy = (mobY - (getHeight() - 2));
    float radiusSum = ((56 / 2) + (256 / 2));
    float distance = (dx * dx) + (dy * dy);
    return distance <= radiusSum * radiusSum;
}

// Checks the collision of bullets.
public boolean bulletCollisionCheck() {
    float centerX = (getWidth() / 2);
    float centerY = (getHeight() - (75 / 2));
    double angle = Math.atan2((centerY - mouse.getMouseY()), (centerX - mouse.getMouseX())) - (Math.PI / 2);

    float dxB = (bulletX - (getWidth() / 2));
    float dyB = (bulletY - (getHeight() - (75 / 2)));
    float distanceBetweenCircles = (float) Math.sqrt((dxB * dxB) + (dyB * dyB));

    float bulletXB = (float) ((getWidth() / 2) + (distanceBetweenCircles * Math.sin(angle)));
    float bulletYB = (float) ((getHeight() - (75 / 2)) - (distanceBetweenCircles * Math.cos(angle)));

    float dx = (mobX - (bulletXB + 3));
    float dy = (mobY - bulletYB);
    float radiusSum = ((56 / 2) + (22 / 2));
    float distance = (dx * dx) + (dy * dy);
    return distance <= radiusSum * radiusSum;
}
```

If someone can please help. I have tried creating the mobs in a different class but then I have to change the x value to a random for each of the different enemies which causes a lot of errors that I can't seem to fix.

EDIT:
Forgot to add the animation class.

```
public class Animation {

    private ArrayList<BufferedImage> Frames = new ArrayList<BufferedImage>();
    private int currentFrame = 0;

    public void addFrame(BufferedImage Frame) {
        Frames.add(Frame);
    }

    public BufferedImage getNextFrame() {
        if (currentFrame == Frames.size()) {
            currentFrame = 0;
        }
        return Frames.get(currentFrame++);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class representing each enemy and a hitbox for each enemy, an area in which the enemy is in and if the turret projectile enters that area the enemy gets damaged. This could be e.g. a rectangle or a circle and the hitbox's coordinates should update every time the enemy moves.
What you're doing is great in order to get some knowledge on fundamental stuff but if you want to do something really good you should use existing frameworks.